# Find xml element and hyperlink C#

Tags: c#

This is what i have in my code

[code]

```
 string m = MesId;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        while ("" != m)
        {

            int splitIndex = m.IndexOf('>');
            if (-1 == splitIndex)
            {
                builder.Append(m);
                break;
            }
            builder.AppendLine(m.Substring(0, splitIndex + 1));
            if (splitIndex == m.Length) { break; }
            m = m.Substring(splitIndex + 1);

        }
        m = builder.ToString();
```

[/code]

string m = MesId; am getting this value from my table (xml column). used the above function to append new line after ">" and load it in to custom message box.

Now i have a real problem i have to hyperlink the element value `<identifier>1268020250775</Identifier>`, i know you can use xpath query to fint the element but already am using as a string.

is this anyway i can hyperlink this value in my custom message box ?

[Hyper link the `<Identifier>` element value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jp9IA.png)

Answer (score 1):

Hey Usher this is not tested but try this.

```
string text = "<identifier>1268020250775</Identifier>";
Regex r1 = new Regex(@"<identifier>(.*?)</Identifier>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match match = r1.Match(text);
if (match.Success)
{
   string v = match.Groups[1].Value;
   string link = "<a href=\""+ v +"\">"+ v +"</a>";
   Response.Write(link);
}
```

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks Bobby,am getting match.success "false" even though i have <identifier> tag in my input.

Comment: Are you sure your identifier tag look like this <identifier>1268020250775</Identifier> notice the second Identifier has capital "I" if not you might have to make the change in regex

Comment: Check the case... is it `<identifier>` or `<Identifier>` ? Maybe you could also ignore the case: `...=new Regex(...,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`

Comment: it is <Identifier>12345</Identifier>,thanks to point me out,so i have to change the regexp to <Identifier>(.*?)</Identifier>"...right

Comment: yep so it will be like this Regex r1 = new Regex(@"<Identifier>(.*?)</Identifier>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Comment: Thanks Bobby this doesn't help me but the other code you gave that solves the problem most